# Map zooming with D3 and Datamaps

Tags: javascript, d3.js, datamaps

I need your help.
I'm using [datamaps](http://datamaps.github.io/) and I want to implement a zoom on a country. I can find loads of examples how I can achieve this, but the difference is, I want to be able to do this with a external button.

Let's say outside of my `<div id="worldmap"></div>` where the map is being rendered I have a button: `<button data-location="AUS">`.
How am I able to zoom using these values? I know the datamaps uses these short names (AUS = australia) to notate the name. I can also provide `long lat` coordinates if this is the way to do it.

Can somebody help me with this issue? I'm fairly new to D3 and datamaps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way could be that you translate and scale to your region of choice using `translate scale` as shown below.

```
function gotoAustralia(){
  map.svg.selectAll(".datamaps-subunits").transition().duration(750).attr("transform", "scale(1.5)translate(-400,-100)");
}
function gotoSouthAmerica(){
  map.svg.selectAll(".datamaps-subunits").transition().duration(750).attr("transform", "scale(1.5)translate(-50,-300)");
}
function reset(){
  map.svg.selectAll(".datamaps-subunits").transition().duration(750).attr("transform", "");
}
```

working code [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/tO9NE1KUBet8zx5Px6E1)

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm looking for a more dynamic solution, but this is enough to get me on the right track. Thanks!